# Save Print Counter To TXT File , PYthon

Tags: python

I wanna to save print result to txt file
my code for scaping website

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from collections import Counter

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
result = driver.get(" U RL ")

city = []

while True:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')

    cities = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'region d-inline-block mr-5'})]

    for i in range(len(cities)):
        city.append(cities[i])

    try:
        driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value='»').click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        break
    count = Counter(city)
    print(count)
    
    with open('example.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(count)

driver.quit()
```

can you help me for save my result to txt file .
thank you for helping

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

Before the print function, save the output to a variable and then save it in a new file.